# How can I cap the length of a dimension? Using pgfmathgreater and ifthenelse causes error: Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 32

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals

I want to cap the length of a dimension. But using pgfmathgreater and ifthenelse results in error. Minimal non working example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\usetikzlibrary{
  arrows.meta,
}

\tikzset{
  pics/my-pic/.style args={#1}{
    code={
      \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\arrowLength}{#1}

      \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\arrowHeadWidth}{\arrowLength / 6}
      \ifthenelse{\pgfmathgreater{\arrowLength}{.5cm} < 1}{
%      \ifthenelse{0>1}{
              \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\arrowHeadWidth}{10pt}
      }{}
      \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\arrowHeadLength}{\arrowHeadWidth / 1.4}

      \draw[-{Latex[round,width=\arrowHeadWidth,length=\arrowHeadLength]}] (0, 0) -- (\arrowLength, 0);
    }
  },
  pics/my-pic/.default=.65cm,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic {my-pic};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The error is

```
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 32.
<inserted text> 
\fi
```

Comment: By the way, PGFmath comes with its own `ifthenelse`: `\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\arrowHeadWidth}{ifthenelse(\arrowLength>.5cm,10pt,\arrowLength/6)}`. Though `\ifdim` will be faster. Technically, you could also do `\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\arrowHeadWidth}{\ifdim\arrowLength>.5cm 10pt\else\arrowLength/6\fi}` but that's … unusual?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot pass `\pgfmathgreater{\arrowLength}{.5cm}` to `\ifthenelse`, because the latter requires something that expands to an integer, not instructions to set `\pgfmathresult` to an integer.

It's simpler.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{
  arrows.meta,
}

\tikzset{
  pics/my-pic/.style args={#1}{
    code={
      \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\arrowLength}{#1}
      \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\arrowHeadWidth}{\arrowLength / 6}
      \ifdim\arrowLength>.5cm
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\arrowHeadWidth}{10pt}
      \fi
      \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\arrowHeadLength}{\arrowHeadWidth / 1.4}

      \draw[-{Latex[round,width=\arrowHeadWidth,length=\arrowHeadLength]}] (0, 0)
        -- (\arrowLength, 0);
    }
  },
  pics/my-pic/.default=.65cm,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic {my-pic};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: Kudos to you for the 1.0m reputation. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: `\pgfmathgreater` doesn't print anything, it just sets `\pgfmathresult`. So `\pgfmathgreater{\arrowLength}{.5cm}\ifthenelse{\pgfmathresult=1}{…}` should work but `\ifdim` or PGFmath's `ifthenelse` is preferred, of course.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I tried with `\pgfmathresult`, but…